# How can I query entries based on a Matrix Block Type?

Tags: matrix, plugin-elementapi

I'm using Element API and trying to create a query that returns a list of entries based on if the entry is using a specific Matrix Block Type.

I've tried a few different things including a query that does a search where the field contains any value, but it's not returning any entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren’t using Element API here, you could do this by adding a condition to the element query:

```php
$query->andWhere(['exists', (new \craft\db\Query())
    ->from(['b' => \craft\db\Table::MATRIXBLOCKS])
    ->innerJoin(\craft\db\Table::MATRIXBLOCKTYPES . ' bt', '[[bt.id]] = [[b.id]]')
    ->where('[[b.ownerId]] = [[elements.id]]')
    ->andWhere(['bt.handle' => 'yourBlockTypeHandle'])
]);
```

But Element API doesn’t give you direct access to the query. I can think of a couple ways to pull it off, though.

---

**Option 1: Implement a custom element query param.**

You could define a new element query behavior class, which wraps that condition into a new `hasBlockType` param:

```php
<?php

use craft\db\Query;
use craft\db\Table;
use craft\elements\db\ElementQuery;
use craft\events\CancelableEvent;
use yii\base\Behavior;

/**
 * @property ElementQuery $owner
 */
class ElementQueryBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public $hasBlockType;

    public function hasBlockType(string $handle)
    {
        $this->hasBlockType = $handle;
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ElementQuery::EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE => [$this, 'prepare'],
        ];
    }

    public function prepare()
    {
        if ($this->hasBlockType) {
            $this->owner->andWhere(['exists', (new Query())
                ->from(['b' => Table::MATRIXBLOCKS])
                ->innerJoin(Table::MATRIXBLOCKTYPES . ' bt', '[[bt.id]] = [[b.id]]')
                ->where('[[b.ownerId]] = [[elements.id]]')
                ->andWhere(['bt.handle' => $this->hasBlockType])
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you’d need to register that behavior with new element query instances, from your [module’s](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html) `init()` method.

```php
\craft\base\Event::on(
    \craft\elements\db\ElementQuery::class,
    \craft\db\Query::EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS,
    function(\craft\events\DefineBehaviorsEvent $event) {
        $event->behaviors['my-behavior'] = new ElementQueryBehavior();
    }
);
```

Finally, from `config/element-api.php`, add this to your endpoint’s `criteria` array:

```php
'criteria' => [
    'hasBlockType' => 'yourBlockTypeHandle',
    // ...
],
// ...
```

The advantage of going this route is that your new `hasBlockType` query param will be available everywhere, so you can reuse it from any element queries you’re writing in Twig or PHP.

---

**Option 2: Use a custom Fractal resource class.**

Element API allows you to define [Fractal resource](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/resources/) class using the [`class`](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api#class) endpoint param.

Yours could extend the built-in [ElementResource](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/blob/v2/src/resources/ElementResource.php) class, overriding its [getElementQuery()](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/blob/v2/src/resources/ElementResource.php#L161-L169) method.

```php
<?php

use craft\db\Query;
use craft\db\Table;
use craft\elementapi\resources\ElementResource;
use craft\elements\db\ElementQueryInterface;

class MyElementResource extends ElementResource
{
    public $hasBlockType;

    protected function getElementQuery(): ElementQueryInterface
    {
        $query = parent::getElementQuery();

        if ($this->hasBlockType) {
            $query->andWhere(['exists', (new Query())
                ->from(['b' => Table::MATRIXBLOCKS])
                ->innerJoin(Table::MATRIXBLOCKTYPES . ' bt', '[[bt.id]] = [[b.id]]')
                ->where('[[b.ownerId]] = [[elements.id]]')
                ->andWhere(['bt.handle' => $this->hasBlockType])
            ]);
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then from `config/element-api.php`, add this to your endpoint config (note that it would **not** go in `criteria`):

```php
'class' => MyElementResource::class,
'hasBlockType' => 'yourBlockTypeHandle',
// ...
```

---

**Option 3: Just use Preparse**

If you only care about a single block type, and don’t really need this to be configurable, the simplest route would be to use the [Preparse Field](https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field) plugin, and actually store whether entries have the block type, as part of their entry data.

For example, if the handle of the Matrix block type you care about is `text`, then you’d create a Preparse field called `hasTextBlock`, with this template:

```php
{{ element.myMatrixField.type('text').exists() ? '1' }}
```

Then resave your entries, and add this to your endpoint’s `criteria` array:

```php
'criteria' => [
    'hasTextBlock' => '1',
    // ...
],
// ...
```

Comment: I think the inner join should look like this:


`->innerJoin(Table::MATRIXBLOCKTYPES . ' bt', '[[bt.id]] = [[b.typeId]]')`