# Element API, query entries where relationship field ':empty:' AND the same relationship field with specified entry ID

Tags: relations, plugin-elementapi

Element API, query entries where relationship field ':empty:' **AND** the same relationship field with specified entry ID.

Can't seem to figure out how to do this without performing two separate queries and merging the objects together. However I don't see a way to perform this within the Element API.

The answer to this other question seems like an approach? Option 1 or Option 2? Not quite sure as this looks all foreign to me with sparse documentation, and it's not specific to my issue.
[How can I query entries based on a Matrix Block Type?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30651/how-can-i-query-entries-based-on-a-matrix-block-type)

Seeing as you can't use ':empty:' with relatedTo, I'm stuck here.

```
return [
    'criteria' => [
        'section' => 'mySection',
        /* this is the myRelatedField entries field relating to other Section Entry ID */
        'relatedTo' => (['targetElement' => $otherSectionEntryId]),
        /* unable to use :empty: with the relatedTo, incorporating myRelatedField :empty: below will return zero results */
        /* cannot use this below */
        'myRelatedField' => ':empty:'
    ],
    'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
        return [
            'title' => $entry->title
        ];
    }
];
```

UPDATE with further testing. Various tests used below in trying to use simple relations with :empty:. It looks as though ':empty:' is ignored when utilized in an array.

```
// results returned where relationship field is empty
'relatedDrinks' => ':empty:'

// no results returned where relationship field is empty
'relatedDrinks' => [':empty:']

// results related to drink ID returned
'relatedDrinks' => [$myDrinkId]

// results returned for drink ID, no results returned with empty
'relatedDrinks' => [':empty:', $myDrinkId]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft will include this functionality in their next release.
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7256#issuecomment-744644568